# Textbox with columns of varying widths

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I am using Microsoft PowerPoint 2016 to create an academic poster. I defined text boxes to hold the contents of each of the different sections and have divided each text box into 2 or 3 columns for optimal text layout.

The problem is, an optimal layout of the text often requires that the columns be of different widths, whereas PowerPoint only allows setting a single width for all, in addition to setting the empty space in between them (not helpful).

Has anyone discovered a workaround to have columns of unequal width, or will I just need to create separate text boxes where before I had columns within a single text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do this might be to use a table. With the table you can adjust each column separately. If you don't want to see the lines around a cell or shading inside cells, simply select "no border" and "no fill" in Table Styles. This approach might be easier than creating multiple text boxes.

Comment: @z8080, the best way to thank Adam is to mark his post as the answer. Click the checkmark on his posting.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I am of course aware of that option - I was just giving this thread a few more days, in case a workaround involving the proposed object type (text boxes) was going to be made.